# Appcenter UWP analytics Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-app-center

Implemented AppCenter analytics as per documentation and using secret from HockeyApp (No Setting page in App Center).

```
AppCenter.Start("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", typeof(Analytics));
```

Causing the following authorization error

```
[AppCenter] ERROR: Sending logs for channel 'core', batch 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' failed: HTTP response status=401 (Unauthorized) payload=CorrelationId: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy  ReasonCode: AppSecretDenied 

[AppCenter] ERROR: Sending logs for channel 'analytics', batch 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' failed: HTTP response status=401 (Unauthorized) payload=CorrelationId: yyyyyyyyyyy  ReasonCode: AppSecretDenied
```

And the following error on `TrackEvent`

```
[AppCenter] WARN: Channel is disabled; logs are discarded
```

Comment: Just to make sure: did you replace the string "Your app secret" with your actual generated app secret?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT already replaced “Your App Secret” with secret from setting in hockeyapp.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the App Center app secret here. This is not in the Settings page, but on the **Overview** page. Go to your app in the App Center and click on the **Overview** tab. Here you should see the **Getting Started** guide, which should directly show the exact code you must use (the app secret is redacted in the screenshot):

[image: App secret]